# Windows 10 not seeing external drive

Tags: windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, windows-10

I can no longer see my external hard drive (Seagate Backup Plus 3TB) in Windows Explorer after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

I **can** see the drive in `devices and printers` and `device manager` as seen below

[image]

<sup>*Devices and printers*</sup>

---

[image]

<sup>*Device manager*</sup>

---

This is what the `disk manager` looks like, where the missing drive is `Disk 1`
[image]

<sup>*Disk manager*</sup>

***Note:*** I've tried reconnecting the drive, updating drivers, restarting the computer but it's still not working.

---

**Update 1:** I'm getting the same problem on another computer running Windows 10.

**Update 2:** On my other computer I tried running Ubuntu instead and there I **can** see the drive and use its files.

**Update 3:** I tried connecting the drive to a third computer, though running Windows 8.1 instead, and I'm still having the same problem.

**Update 4:** When running `gdisk` in Ubuntu it says:

```
Partition table scan:
   MBR: MBR only
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: not present

**********************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR
to GPT format in memory. THIS OPERATION IS
POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by typing 'q' if
you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
**********************************************
```

Comment: What happens if you give the partition a drive letter? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Then I get an error saying "The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console view is not up-to-date.  Refresh the view by using the refresh task.  If the problem persists close the Disk Management console, then restart Disk Management or restart the computer."

Comment: And you tried all of the suggestions (refresh, restart DM, restart PC)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Hmm. No more ideas at the moment ... some Windows 10 bug maybe?

Comment: Maybe, added some updates to my question.